# A Uniform Mapping From the Irrationals to the Rationals via Vitali

Tags: equivalence-relations, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, uniform-distribution

If the irrationals in [0,1] are partitioned into an uncountable number of countable sets via the use of Vitali equivalence classes and each set is then bijected with the set of rationals on the interval [0, 1), then can there be a uniform mapping from the irrationals of [0,1] onto the rationals of [0, 1)?  I believe the answer should be no, but an example of this has sat for a day or two and am looking for some feedback:

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/selecting-a-natural-and-a-real-uniformly-at-random.911544/

Comment: What do you mean by 'uniform mapping'?

Comment: A bijection from each equivalence class onto the rationals would be uniform, assuming we had an uncountable number of bijections.  For example, we could just say f(x) = 0.5 in which case, if looking at it in terms of probability (as though an irrational were selected randomly), then the probability of relating to 0.5 is 1.  I am implying that given a random irrational, then a rational would be selected uniformly at random.  PS - I am aware that uniform distributions should not be able to exist across countably infinite sets like the rationals, so thinking it's not possible, but see the example

Comment: Also, if you choose not to respond to this question further I completely respect that, but since I'm admittedly a novice at best compared to some of the extraordinary people here, would you briefly comment as to why you choose not to respond further?  I'm just trying to learn, not thinking I broke math or anything.  Thank you!

Comment: I simply don't understand your question. It is a basic fact in probability that there is no way to select uniformly an element from a countable set (like rationals, or integers), so this question seems quite odd. The argument in the link is incomplete and not very clear, so I am not able to say wether it's correct or not. Anyway, my opinion is that there must be some mistake over there.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that I need to be more clear.  I added a third post to the above link that I think will suffice.  Are you willing to look at only post #3 in the above link?  I apologize and I really appreciate your time.

Comment: I continue not to understand what you mean by 'uniform'. I could interpret it as "the probability of picking some (rational) number inside a set of Lebesgue measure $p$ is $p$", but then I don't see why your map is indeed uniform, since the Vitali set is not Lebesgue measurable. If you have a simpler notion of uniformity, please tell me what it is (see my very first question!). Another problem is that you don't justify why $k$ is indeed surjective: you simply state that without explaining why.

Comment: Yes,  Let A= {1, 2} and B = {3, 4, 5, 6}.  Let f(x) = 1 if x is odd and f(x) = 2 if x is even, then function f would be "uniform" from B to A in the sense that, if we selected an element x of B uniformly at random, then f(x) in A is also selected uniformly at random.  Note that in order to do this, I effectively partitioned B into sets the same size as set A.  In the above link, [0,1] is partitioned into countable sets that are then bijected with the naturals.  Selecting an element of [0,1] uniformly at random then allows for the selection of a natural uniformly at random.  Make sense?